# Mysql date range between given date date range

Tags: mysql

In my table structure mention below

Create tables using the GitHub-flavored markdown format

| id | course | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | course 1 | 2022-03-28 | 2022-03-28 |
| 2 | course 2 | 2022-03-28 | 2022-03-30 |

while searching in my query I give input of date any course start date and end date between the below-given data range.

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-28 | 2022-03-28 |
| 2022-03-27 | 2022-03-28 |
| 2022-03-27 | 2022-03-30 |
| 2022-03-28 | 2022-03-30 |
| 2022-03-27 | 2022-03-31 |

The above all condition date given the result.

Comment: What exactly is the requirement here? You need all courses with given start date  and end date range?

Answer (score 0):

there are two formats to achieve your goals:

first one:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column >= '2014-01-01' AND date_column <= '2015-01-01';
```

second one:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column BETWEEN '2014-01-10' AND '2015-01-01';
```

you can choose any one one and just put the real table and columns

**update based on comment**

the provided is just an example and you can use both columns start_date and end_date as example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column_1 >= '2014-01-01' AND date_column_2 <= '2015-01-01';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

In my condition is i am given both start date and end date search in the DB start date and end date

Comment: no problem, use any one and put your columns star and end. it doesn't matter